# Pass dropzone uploaded filename to hidden input field

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone

I have 2 form in one page, first:dropzone and second is :a form that user need to fill. I want to make when user uploaded a file in dropzone it will add an hidden input in second form. Here are my form

```
<form action="/users/upload.php" class="dropzone needsclick dz-clickable" id="poster"></form>
 <form action='' method='post' name='create' enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div id="ideaform"></div>
</form>
```

and here is my upload.php

```
    <?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];       
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
    $x = explode('.', $name);
    $ext = strtolower(end($x));
    $name = md5(time().$name).'.'.$ext;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, 'images/uploaded/'.$name);
}
?>
```

and i explored the internet about this method to get a filename and put it on value on hidden input and found this jQuery and whenever i tried to upload the files, the value on hidden input always "undefined"

```
 Dropzone.options.poster = {
                maxFiles:1,
                acceptedFiles: "image/*",
                init: function() {
                      this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
                            this.removeAllFiles();
                            this.addFile(file);
                      });
                    this.on('success', function(file, response) {
                    $("#ideaform").append($('<input type="hidden" ' + 'name="files" ' + 'value="' + response.fileName + '">'));
                    });
                }
            };
```

Where am i going wrong?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions that i found is by using JSON. Here are the code:

```
Dropzone.options.poster = {
                acceptedFiles: "image/*",
                maxFilesize: 5, // MB
                maxFiles: 1,
                init: function() {
                      this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
                            this.removeAllFiles();
                            this.addFile(file);
                      });

                    this.on('success', function(file, response) {
                    JSON.parse(response);
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#ideaform").append($('<input type="hidden" name="file"  value='+response+'>'));
                    });
                }
            };
```

and for the form action i got this

```
    <?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];       
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name']; 
    $x = explode('.', $name);
    $ext = strtolower(end($x));
    $name = md5(time().$name).'.'.$ext;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile, 'images/uploaded/'.$name);
    $ar = $name;
    echo json_encode($ar);
}
?>
```

Comment: Frustrating - your code looks good but the response I receive is always empty.